# Sales Force API ( iOS) - Pull self data only

Tags: ios, ipad, salesforce

I have been using Sales force API from quiet a while to pull data from various tables that are there in my sales force account which is further linked to a bigger database.

When I try to pull records from any table, then it pulls all records (belong to all users linked to Database) instead of pulling only those records for which I am authorized too.

Is there a way using which I will be able to pull out records for which I am authorized to instead of all records?

Thanks,

Reno Jones

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet of your code + the API that you're using to get the data. Is there no way to pass in a UserID to the method you're calling? Isn't there perhaps another API that you can use? This almost sounds like a security vulnerability or a poorly designed API library...

Comment: This is the API  I am using - https://github.com/superfell/zkSforce

Here is a simple query to pull out the all the information that I have in my lead table (but I would like to have only information that is for me)

// This is a sample query:

NSString *QueryForPullingLeadInformation = @"Select Name,Id From Lead where IsRemoved=false order by Name";


// This is how I make request to pull records:

        [[FDCServerSwitchboard switchboard] queryAll:QueryForPullingLeadInformation target:self selector:@selector(accountsQueryResponse:error:) context:nil];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user on Salesforce is being given enough ability to see all of the Leads in the org. You either need to change the permissions on the profile of that user or add a filter in the query on the OwnerId field:

"Select Name,Id From Lead where IsRemoved=false and OwnerId = 'myUserIdGoesHere' order by Name"

There is nothing wrong with the library (I have used it extensively) it is your query/security settings.

Paul

Comment: I have tried using the OwnerId in my query, but we do not have the right to create anything on sales force, hence the ownership is in the hands of admin. (In this case I won't be able to have anything as a response as I haven't created anything).

Comment: It was a nice answer though, I am not aware of how to change my permissions in my profile to be able to see the data I am authorized too.

Comment: I would recommend contacting you Admin as you need to have the sharing model setup correctly. Or are you saying that your admin is the only one creating data on your org?

Comment: yes, thats what I am saying, only a few admins (3-4) are allowed to create data. how will i deal with this situation now? Thanks.

Comment: What I am having issues understanding is how your access is limited normally then? You say originally about you having authorisation to only certain records. Any idea how that is done? Do you have a separate login account to these admins for yourself?

Comment: No bro, what I am saying is, I am able to view and pull everything instead of pulling/viewing which only "I" should be able to - i.e. what I am authorized too but I want to know how can I make this happen - "pull the data which is only mine from the database". But I am not the admin, so these records are not created by me.

Comment: The API respects the sharing security setup by the admin, it appears that perhaps your admin is restricting access to records you can view in some other (clearly unsecure) way.

Comment: I agree with superfell, you need to chat to your admin to find out how they are restricting your record visbility. The fact that you are able to retrieve all the results mean you are authorised to see all the results really. My expectation is that they have set up some sort of list view structure to restrict your record visibility in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing some of your code. Here's how you should modify your query:

NSString *QueryForPullingLeadInformation = @"Select Name,Id From Lead where IsRemoved=false **AND OwnerId = [your_owner_id]** order by Name";

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for writing back and modifying the query on the basis of ownerId. I tried this already, but as I am not the owner of the fields (records created in my account, rather I am not allowed to enter the data in my sales force - only admins are allowed to fill database), but I don't know how can I pull the data which is for me only. Thanks though. :)